# How do i setMediaPlayer inside of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a fragment where i am using media player and using my own custom controller class. I am not being able to set controller.setMediaPlayer inside fragment. I have implemented VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl class in fragment.

My fragment class is :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl {

@BindView(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer)
FrameLayout videoContainer;
@BindView(R.id.videoSurface)
SurfaceView videoSurface;
@BindView(R.id.progress)
ProgressBar progressBar;
@BindView(R.id.errorTv)
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
@BindView(R.id.errorTextView)
TextView errorTextView;


public MediaPlayer player;
public VideoControllerView controller;
private  Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

    player = new MediaPlayer();

    controller = new VideoControllerView(getActivity());

    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    playVideo("http://202.166.200.170:8081/otv/aastha.stream/playlist.m3u8");

    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                player.reset();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                playVideo("http://202.166.200.170:8081/otv/aastha.stream/playlist.m3u8");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    player.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

}


public void playVideo(String link) {
    try {
        videoSurface.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (controller.isShowing())
                    controller.hide();
                else
                    controller.show();

                return false;
            }

        });

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                controller.setMediaPlayer();
                controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
                player.start();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (relativeLayout.isShown())
                    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse(link));
        try {

            player.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                errorMessage("Streaming Error");
                player.reset();
                errorTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_video));
                return false;
            }
        });

        player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        Log.d("after click", "last try");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void errorMessage(String message) {
    try {
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void start() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {

}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isFullScreen() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void toggleFullScreen() {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;

}
```

if you see inside playVideo method inside setOnpreparedListener i am getting error in controller.setMediaPlayer() because i am not being able to pass the context here.

what can be done here to solve the error?

Comment: use player.getContext()

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can use controller.setMediaPlayer()

```
// Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) 
 findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
player.start();
}
// End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
```

[This is example to use costume controller](http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller)

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could get the context from there using `HomeFragment.this.getContext()`, like:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            controller.setMediaPlayer(HomeFragment.this.getContext());
            controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
            player.start();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (relativeLayout.isShown())
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just moved `controller.setMediaPlayer(this);` to onCreateView and it worked.